# webview not working in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to load a series of urls based on the contents of my database i.e:  http://www.whatever.com but when I run the app in the simulator nothing appears, my code reads as follows

#### .h file (imports statements excluded)

```
@interface FSFourthScreenViewController : UIViewController

//insert code to create web view
{
    NSString * urlString;
    UIWebView * FSWebView;
}

// properties
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * urlString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView * FSWebView;

@end
```

#### .m file import statements excluded

```
@interface FSFourthScreenViewController ()

@end

@implementation FSFourthScreenViewController

@synthesize FSWebView, urlString;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //background image
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundimage.png"]];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest * requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [FSWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I have wired the webview correctly, and assigned the right field in the database.  I also cleaned out xCode and the simulator, but still no joy... any ideas welcome?

Comment: Do you have any proxy settings? If yes set the same in simulator and try. Can you test it in an iOS device.

Comment: Have you connected the IBOutlets properly?

Comment: Have you tested going to Safari in the simulator and trying to access the web page. If you cannot get to the web page then you have a connection issue. If you can get to it then you have an issue with your code

Comment: don't have proxy settings - its a very, very simple app (uni project) and yes, def' set the IBOutlets

Comment: As adam suggested try loading the page from safari and try. Also how are you setting the URL string? check whether its null.

Answer (score 1):

add this code ,check your objects:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //background image
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundimage.png"]];

        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        if (!url)
        {
            NSLog(@"url is nil!!!");
        }


        NSURLRequest * requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        if (!FSWebView)
        {
            NSLog(@"RSWebView is nil!!!");
        }

        [FSWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    }
```

i guess the url is nil ,or the webview is nil

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
[self.FSWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `urlString`. In the code you provided, the `urlString` is never set, so the `URL` you create with it cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial :

http://mrudulajampala.blogspot.ca/2012/10/uiwebview-tutorial.html

And you find its source code here:

https://sites.google.com/site/iphonesdktutorials/sourcecode/UIWebViewTutorialPart1.zip?attredirects=0

Hopefully it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you havent `UIWebViewDelegate` in your `FSFourthScreenViewController.h`. You need to add it and to add its delegate `WebView` methods to your `FSFourthScreenViewController.m`

Check documentation for more details of `UIWebViewDelegate` :

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is iOS6 and abrove you can use this tool the web inspector to be sure that the web page is loading without any error.

You can follow this tutorial :

http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

i hope it will help you to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. But your urlString is null . That is why it is not showing anything.
you just add an an url , and then test for it

Answer (score -1):

Add

`<UIWebViewDelegate>` in your view controller

```
self.FSWebView.delegate=self;
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.wrightscs.com"]; //replace your string here
  [self.FSWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: How is this going to help him? Please explain!

Comment: sorted it guy, thank you.  needed url as URL... don't know why, but it works now.

Comment: @AngS77  If it is useful then you can accept my answer.